# Sending Raw HTTP requests bypassing DNS resolution

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, https, http

I am migrating from old hosting right now to a new one. My DNS records currently point to the old server.

I want to test how do the new server works, but as far as DNS records pointing to the old one, there is only one option to get a response is to send a raw HTTP request directly to the new server bypassing DNS resolution.

Is it possible to do this ? I am looking for some software that will be able to do this.

Could you suggest any tools ?

Comment: Put the new IP address in your hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass DNS lookups by adding an entry to the [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file.

You would want to add

```
192.0.2.6  www.example.com
```

Where `192.0.2.6` and `www.example.com` should be replaced by the new server's IP address and the hostname respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `curl` to make HTTP requests to an IP address with a hostname like this:

```
curl --resolve www.example.com:80:192.168.100.100 http://www.example.com
```

This tells CURL to connect to `192.168.100.100:80` when connecting to `http://www.example.com`